# HTML form pattern validation - Prevent validation message from appearing with every keypress

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a basic form with pattern validation that looks like this...

```html
<form>
 <label for="username">Username <i>(letters and numbers only, no  punctuation or special characters)</i></label><br>
 <input name="username" id="username" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+">
</form>
```

This works correctly, if I enter a `dash` into the input and press enter then the message `Please match the format requested is displayed`

But it then keeps displaying after every keypress into the input field.

How can I change this so that the message only appears once on pressing enter?